# Fullcalendar - Events from json feed form another directory

Tags: json, fullcalendar

Hi i have small problem with my json feed that creates events.

This configure events with i call later with: $('#calendar').fullCalendar("addEventSource", source.month)

```
var source = {
    month: {
                url: 'events_month.php',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: true,
                color: '#4AB8E7',
                textColor: 'white',
                className: 'month'
            },
```

I wanted to clear my directory a little bit, and copied events_month.php to events/events_month.php. Changed the code to:

```
 month: {
                url: 'events/events_month.php',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: true,
                color: '#4AB8E7',
                textColor: 'white',
                className: 'month'
            },
```

But it stopped to show events in my fullcalendar. No console errors. Please help figure this out.